# Call function on boost::variant regardless of type?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, boost-variant

I have a class which has a template:

```
 template<class T = int> class slider;
```

The class has a `void Process(void)` method, so, I think it should be callable regarless of the type, return value is void and there are no parameters to it.

As for now I have this code to call process each frame in my application:

```
//class menu:
typedef boost::variant<std::shared_ptr<slider<int>>,std::shared_ptr<slider<float>>,std::shared_ptr<slider<double>>,std::shared_ptr<slider<char>>> slider_type;
std::map<std::string,slider_type> Sliders;
//buttons ... etc ...
void Process()
{
    if(!Sliders.empty())
    {
        for(auto i = Sliders.begin(); i != Sliders.end(); ++i)
        {
            switch(i->second.which())
            {
                case 0://slider<int>
                {
                    boost::get<std::shared_ptr<slider<int>>>(i->second)->Process();
                    break;
                }
                case 1://slider<float>
                {
                    boost::get<std::shared_ptr<slider<float>>>(i->second)->Process();
                    break;
                }
                //.....
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to execute the functions Process() like in the following example?

```
    for(auto i = Sliders.begin(); i != Sliders.end(); ++i)
    {
        switch(i->second.which())
        {
            boost::get<???Any???>(i->second)->Process();
        }
    }
```

If yes, how?

Comment: This sounds like [an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to do here that you *want* to do this? And most importantly, *why aren't you using a visitor?*

Answer (score 5):

What would such a function return? You can't change the type of a function at *runtime*. And the point of a variant is that it's contents are determined at *runtime*.

The only thing it could return is a `boost::any`. Which is really just exchanging one kind of unknown for another (an unknown that's a *lot* harder to deal with when you don't know what it contains, mind you). But if you want to see such a visitor:

```
struct convert_to_any : public boost::static_visitor<boost::any>
{
  template<typename T> boost::any operator() (const T& t) {return t;}
};
```

Use `apply_visitor` on that, and you will get an `any` back. Though I fail to see how that's helpful.

---

In any case, if you're using `get` on a `variant`, you are almost certainly doing the wrong thing. The correct way to access the elements of a variant is with a *visitor*, not with `get`.

In your case, the visitor should be simple:

```
struct ProcessVisitor : public boost::static_visitor<>
{
  template<typename T> void operator() (const T& t) const {t->Process();}
};
```

Just use `apply_visitor` on that. If the variant contains a type that can be used with `operator->` and the return value of that function can have `Process` called on it, then it will.

Answer (score 4):

(Untested code!)

```
struct CallProcess : static_visitor<>
{
  template <class T>
  void operator()(const T &t) const
  {
    t->Process();
  }
};

for(auto i = Sliders.begin(); i != Sliders.end(); ++i)
{
  boost::apply_visitor(CallProcess(), i->second);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, not at all. You have to visit and deal with the case of every type. That is much better done with a visitor than your switch hack.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible because `boost::variant` has no way to know that all the types in the `variant` have anything in common.  In fact, since the compiler generates a distinct class for each template specialization used, the address of the `Process()` function that would need to be used is different for each type in the `boost::variant`.  To get around this you could abandon `variant` and use virtual functions and polymorphic classes sharing a common base class.

Comment: An example would be really great, I have never in C++ made anything like a base class and user class :$